# calculation gradients of tf.nn.embedding_lookup

Tags: python, tensorflow, embedding-lookup

```
import tensorflow as tf
types_lookup_table = tf.get_variable("types_lookup_table", shape=[234, 10],initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(0, 1), dtype=tf.float32,
trainable=True)
embedding_types = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(types_lookup_table,[[2,3,4],[1,2,3]])
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
gradients = tf.gradients(embedding_types, xs=types_lookup_table) 
train = opt.apply_gradients([(gradients[0], types_lookup_table)])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    h = sess.run(gradients)
    print(sess.run(train)) #right
    print(sess.run(opt.apply_gradients([(h[0],types_lookup_table)]))). # wrong
```

I tried to calculate the gradients of `tf.nn.embedding_lookup`, but the result shown is an *IndexedSliceValue* with 3 elements.

[image: h]

However the corresponding gradient(without sess.run) is an indexSliceValue with 1 elements.I don't know why.
[image: gradients]

And therefore I can't

`sess.run(opt.apply_gradients([(h[0],types_lookup_table)])`
 because the shape of calculation value doesn't match the shape of _types_lookup_table_, however, when I didn't calculate the intermediate value, and directly

```
sess.run(train) (ps:train = opt.apply_gradients([(gradients, types_lookup_table)]))
```

There is no problem.

But I need to calculate the intermediate value and do an add. I don't know how.
Thanks

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: thanks. This is a complete code, and its very small, so I chose to put it all on the web.